# Why does ftp script fail with /home/dbadmin is a directory error?

Tags: bash, ftp-client

Given the following script

```
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd /home/dbadmin/backup
mput *.gz
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

the `mput *.gz` from a directory `/backups` that contains *.gz files, results in this error:

`mput t1.gz? mput t2.gz? ./temp.sh: line 14: /home/dbadmin: is a directory`

I am not sure how to change the script without `put`ting individual file names. I want to `mput` all files in this directory.

By putting an exit 0 after END_SCRIPT, the error disappeared, and I am interested in why this happened.

Comment: what is the line 14 of this script?

Comment: Line 14 was the end of the script, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about to replace mput to generated `put`?

```
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd /home/dbadmin/backup
$(find *.gz -maxdepth 0 -type f -printf 'put %p\n')
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

How it works:

When HERE-IS-DOCUMENT will be resolved, `find *.gz ...` will generate multiple lines for each file found by mask `*.gz`:

```
put 1.gz
put 2.gz
...
```

and your script content that will be executed by `ftp` will be like that:

```
quote USER your_user_name
quote PASS your_passwd
cd /home/dbadmin/backup
put 1.gz
put 2.gz
...
quit
```

Regarding `/home/dbadmin: Is a directory` I belive you have single line `/home/dbadmin` in your script (or something like `$SOME_COMMAND /home/dbadmin`).